# RazorSQL - Not able to connect to Cassandra DB

Tags: jdbc, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-jdbc, razorsql

I am trying to connect to CassandraDB through RazorSQL. I am new to RazorSQL.

Steps followed:

1. In the topmenu --> 
   Connections --> Add connection profile --> Entering all the details in the popmenu which appears (driver location, host, port number, etc.)

I tried with AutoDownload Driver option in RazorSQL, and also tried with various Cassandra JDBC Drivers.

cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5, cassandra-jdbc-2.1.1, CassandraJdbcDriver.zip, DataStaxCassandraODBC32.

## I am getting this error msg:

ERROR: An error occurred while trying to make a connection to the 
database:

JDBC URL: jdbc:cassandra://88.198.37.102:9042

org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative 
frame size (-2113929216)!

[image]

Can anyone help me how to connect to Cassandra DB using this.. thank you very much in advance.

Comment: are you able to list all the tables..Unfortunately it does not work for me

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with RazorSQL and can't see the dialog, but the error message indicates that you are trying to connect a thrift client to the Cassandra native protocol default port (9042).

You should be able to connect to the Thrift server on 9160. Depending on your version of Cassandra, you may need to enable it in cassandra.yaml:

```
start_rpc: true
```

Comment: Once I set the value, Im able to connect to the cassandra but it does not list all the tables from  a paritcular keyspace

Comment: Is it necessary that i need to connect to the thrift port? Is there no way to connect to the default port i.e. 9042?

Comment: Unless you are changing the server configuration, that port speaks a completely different protocol. 9160 is legacy thrift. 9042 is CQL native protocol.